# show difference message by comparing to string using ngIf

Tags: angular

I am trying to show different message on the basis of the string which I have using ngIf in angular but it is not working correctly

```
{{time}}
<div *ngIf="time !='the time which you selected'">
<p>
  The item will be picked up by our Style Delivery Associate on
  <strong>{{message}}</strong> between
  <strong>{{time}}</strong>.Please Keep the item ready with the original tag intact.
   Thank you!
</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="time =='the time which you selected'">
<p>
  The item will be picked up by our Style Delivery Associate on
  <strong>{{message}}</strong>.Please Keep the item ready with the original tag intact. 
  Thank you!
</p>
</div>
```

output of `{{time}}`

[image]

Comment: How does it behave? What would be the correct behavior?

Comment: It should show the first div if time value is not equal to the string 'the time which you selected' otherwise if second div.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't do that. Can you try to reproduce in http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Perhaps `console.log` or `print` out the `time`? and compare with the `string`?

Comment: can you show output of `{{time}}`

Comment: yes I am doing that.. wait..

Comment: attached the screenshot

Comment: Just to make sure... there's no trailing spaces?

Comment: no dude there is no space

Comment: There is trailing space. See what is printed in the middle of the screenshot. "which you selected . Please ..."

Comment: but I am comparing it with {{time}}, right? even though I removed that space. now it look like the updated snippet

Comment: Hmm? Your `time` outputs `'the time which you selected '` which is `!=` to `'the time which you selected'`

Comment: ok, so it should work if I compare like this <div *ngIf="time !='the time which you selected '"> no luck man :(

Comment: Give it a try...? But yes it should work since `time` have a trailing space...

Comment: hey, it worked. thanks man :)